# What's wrong with this formula for the dot product of a vector and a matrix acting on that vector?

Tags: matrices, summation

Suppose we have an $n \times n$ matrix $M$ and a vector $v$. I want to find an explicit formula for $v \cdot Mv$. I begin by saying $$v \cdot Mv = \sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i(Mv)_i$$ and since $Mv$ is given by the vector composed of the dot products of the rows of $M$ with $v$, we say $$(Mv)_i = R_i \cdot v$$ where $R_i$ is the $i$th row vector of M, so $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i(Mv)_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i (R_i \cdot v) = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \sum_{j=1}^n(R_i)_j v_j$$ $(R_i)_j$ is the jth element of the ith row, so we can replace it with $a_{ij}$. Substituting and rearranging, we get
$$\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\sum_{j=1}^nv_j \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^na_{ij} = (\sum_{i=1}^n v_i)^2 Sum(M)$$where we use $Sum(M)$ to represent the sum of all the elements in the matrix (as that is the summation over all $a_{ij}$).

Trouble is, I tried my formula and it didn't work. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is when you made the substitution $(R_i)_j=a_{ij}$. You should have
$$\sum_{i=1}^nv_i\sum_{j=1}^n(R_i)_jv_j=\sum_{i=1}^nv_i\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}v_j.$$
Now neither $a_{ij}$ nor $v_j$ can be pulled out of the sum over $j$ as both depend on $j$. The formula isn't going to "simplify" beyond this.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're saying is something like this:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n (R_k)_jv_j=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n (R_k)_j\right) \left( \sum_{j=1}^n v_j \right)$$
This is your mistake: **summations are not distributive over multiplication**. This is like saying the following:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n (1)(1)=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n 1\right) \left( \sum_{j=1}^n 1\right)$$
Clearly, the left side is $n$ while the right side is $n^2$, so this kind of manipulation is invalid by this counterexample.

Comment: Is there any way to manipulate $\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} v_i v_j$ into a more useful form?

Comment: @SquarerootSquirrel Unless we know more about $v$ and $M$, I'm pretty sure the form in kccu's answer is simplest.

Comment: In the problem that motivated this question, M is symmetric and positive definite. Does that help?

Comment: @SquarerootSquirrel No, I don't think that really simplifies the formula down anymore.